# Can I set global fx properties in MooTools?

Tags: javascript, mootools, effects

Is there a way to set some default properties for MooTools effects like duration or transition?

That would make it easier to make all those effects like `element.tween();` or `element.reveal()` uniform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use implement() to overwrite the default values.

```
Fx.implement({options: {duration: 600}})
```

Comment: See http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class#Class:implement for more information on this function.